# Issues with WP Shortcode output wrapping around content

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, shortcode

I want to wrap an opening and closing shortcode function in WordPress around a `get_template_part('path/file')`. Instead of the code wrapping around in the HTML output, it shows below the content.

Example below:

**PHP output:**

```
<?php 
function get_products($atts = [], $output = null) { 

    PHP outout:
    $output= get_template_part('partials/modules/content', 'fields');
    $output .= '[shortcode]'. $output .'[/shortcode]';
    $output .= ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
    }

add_shortcode('resources', 'get_products');
?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[resources]'); ?>
```

**Html output:**

```
<div class="content">
</div>

<div class="shortcode">
</div>
```

**Html desired output:**

```
<div class="shortcode">
<div class="content">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: yes I mean. output. sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
function my_template( $attr ) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'partials/modules/content' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'template', 'my_template' );

function get_products($atts = [], $output = null) { 

    return "
        <div class='shortcode'>
            ".do_shortcode('[template]')."
        </div>
    ";
}

add_shortcode('resources', 'get_products');
```

Comment: looks like it still doesn't wrap around to content. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @PaulSolomon try this new e.g